# Logistic model, what is more important: Chi sq test or significance of coefficients

Tags: r

I have a logistic model with 8 variables. I ran a chi square test in R (anova(glm.model,test='Chisq')) and 2 of the variables turn out to be predictive when ordered at the top of the test and not so much when ordered at the bottom. the summary(glm.model) suggests that their coefficients are insignificant (high p-value). In this case it seems that the variables are not significant.

I wanted to ask which is a better test of variables significance - the coefficient significance in the model summary or the chi square test.

I guess it's a broad question but any pointers on what to consider will be appreciate.

Comment: This is definitely not a stackoverflow question. You should re-ask on Cross Validated (statistics.stackexchange.com).

Answer (score 2):

While I don't have time to fully look into this, I suspect you may want to use type II sums-of-squares, provided by the `Anova` (note case) function in John Fox' `car` library. Type II is not going to care about the order of your predictors.

For details, see your favorite stats text. I've got Fox' Applied Linear Regression. It's pretty good, and has an R companion (and the library mentioned above).